# Анимация персонажей сцены Paris shopping

Tags: svg, анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На просторах интернета встретился вот такой яркий образ - юной парижанки, которая неспешно возвращается после удачного шопинга.

Хочется сделать анимацию этого романтичного образа. В голову приходят различные техники реализации: использование различных `JS` библиотек, но это будет чисто механическое прорисовывание линий одновременно всех персонажей.
 А хочется создать сценарий постепенного появления и раскрашивания отдельных фрагментов на основе последовательно-параллельных эффектов анимаций.
Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 11):

Конечно для решения такой задачи нужен svg файл. Он есть и очень огромный.
 Дизайнер создавал его в векторном редакторе и конечно не думал об оптимизации файла. Он творил,- здесь мазок, там линия, здесь цветные точки. В результате с точки зрения программиста получился полный хаос внутри `svg` файла.

### Оптимизация кода внутри svg файла

- Объединение патчей, которые имеют одинаковый цвет и отвечают за
  небольшие, соседние фрагменты изображения

Находим патчи с одинаковым цветом, допустим - `#E3FFF0` и объединяем их в один патч, соединяя патчи из разных фрагментов:
`<path fill="#E3FFF0"  d="M(цифры)m(цифры)m(цифры))m(цифры)z"/>`

- Присвоение уникальных идентификаторов фрагментам изображения, которые
  будут анимированы

Названия `id` лучше задавать осмысленно, например: для фрагмента кода Эйфелевой башни - `<path id=”Eiffel”` 
для блузки девушки - `id=”Blouse”` и т.д.

Для поиска фрагментов изображения можно воспользоваться простым приемом: в формуле патча(path) нужно подставить `1` перед командой `M(moveto)` и сразу будет видно – какой фрагмент изображения исчезнет.

`<path id="Eiffel" fill="none" stroke="#8DABBA" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray= "4617.95" stroke-dashoffset="4617.95"
   d="1M1466.1 154.2c5.2-0.9 10.4-0.1 15.7 0.1 0.3 46 0 92 0.1 137.9 0.1 0.4 0.3 1.1 0.4 1.5 2.8 0.6 5.6 0.5 8.4 0.6 0.3 5.9`

В нашем случае исчезла Эйфелева башня. Присваиваем этому патчу `id=”Eiffel`
После присвоения `id` убираем единичку перед `M`

- Система присвоения имен `id` командам анимации

Допустим вы решили сделать следующую последовательность выполнения анимаций:
 - Эйфелевая башня ➔ 2. голова девушки ➔ 3. тело девушки ➔ 4. кофточка ➔
 - юбка
`id="Eiffel"` ➔ 2. `id="Head"` ➔ 3. `id="BodyWoman"` ➔ 4. `id="Blouse"` ➔
 - `id="Skirt"`

### Последовательность команд выполнения анимаций

Последовательность выполнения анимаций словами звучит так:

- после окончания выполнения анимации Эйфелевой башни запускается
  анимация прорисовки головы девушки.
- Команда запуска этой анимации `begin = "EiffelFill.end"`
- Команда запуска анимации тела девушки начинается после завершения прорисовки головы девушки – `begin = "HeadStroke.end"`
  и так далее по составленной последовательности выполнения анимаций.

Параллельно можно запускать другие анимации, например вместе с анимацией головы девушки запускать параллельно анимацию прорисовки пуделя. Другими словами, команда запуска для этих анимаций будет общей: `begin = "EiffelFill.end"`

*В любой момент вы можете изменить, по своему вкусу, порядок выполнения анимаций.*
 Для этого достаточно изменить порядок выполнения команд `begin=”…end”` запуска анимаций.
Весь код анимации очень большой, поэтому вынесен на отдельный источник.

*Пример анимации Эйфелевой башни*

Наведите курсор на контур башни

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="200" height="300" viewBox="1000 550 1600 1600">    
  <path  id="Eiffel" fill="#F3FFFE" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="2" stroke-dasharray= "4617.95" stroke-dashoffset="0" 
   d="M1466.1 154.2c5.2-0.9 10.4-0.1 15.7 0.1 0.3 46 0 92 0.1 137.9 0.1 0.4 0.3 1.1 0.4 1.5 2.8 0.6 5.6 0.5 8.4 0.6 0.3 5.9 0.1 11.8 0.2 17.7 4.7 0.3 9.4 0.3 14.1 0.3 2.4 10.5-0.5 21.6 1.5 32.2 3.9 1.6 8.3 0.4 12.5 0.7 1.4 0.2 4-0.3 3.7 1.9 0.6 11.6 0 23.2 0.2 34.8 -5.6 0.2-11.2 0-16.8 0.3 0.4 3.3 0.8 6.6 0.9 9.9 1.3 23.7 3.8 47.3 5.1 71 1.8 20.3 3.1 40.7 4.8 61 0.2 12.6 2.1 25 2.6 37.6 1.3 23.3 3.8 46.6 5 70 2.3 21 2.6 42.2 5 63.2 0.8 6.3 0.4 12.6 1 18.8 1.2 11.8 2.3 23.6 2.7 35.4 1.5 15.1 2.3 30.2 3.4 45.3 0.8 12.7 2.2 25.4 3 38.1 0.9 14.2 1.8 28.5 3.1 42.7 1 12.4 1.5 24.8 2.9 37.2 0.7 5.3 0.3 10.7 1.1 16.1 2 23.5 3.1 47.1 5.3 70.6 0.1 5 0.1 10 1.3 14.9 11.5 0.6 23.1-0.2 34.7 0.3 0.7 15-0.4 30.1 0.5 45.2 0.2 1.6-1.6 2.3-2.9 2.1 -5.8-0.4-11.6-0.5-17.5-0.2 -0.2 4.2 1.7 7.9 3.1 11.8 6.4 20.9 12.8 41.9 19.4 62.7 2.6 10 5.9 19.9 9.1 29.7 2.9 10.1 5.9 20.1 9.2 30 3.1 12.1 7.7 23.8 11 35.8 2.2 8.2 5.5 16.1 7.5 24.4 0.6 1.5 0.7 4 2.8 4.3 8.2 0.9 16.6-0.4 24.9 0.4 2.2-0.3 1.6 2.3 1.9 3.7 0 10.3-0.1 20.7 0.1 31 -0.1 2.2 0.3 4.7-1.2 6.6 -3.9 0.9-7.9 0.6-11.8 0.7 2.4 6.1 6.1 11.6 9.3 17.4 9.8 18.6 20.8 36.6 31 55 2.3 5.5 6.1 10 8.7 15.3 4.9 9.4 10.6 18.3 15.4 27.7 3.9 6.4 7.9 12.9 11.1 19.8 4.2 6.6 7.6 13.7 11.7 20.4 2.3 4.9 5.9 9.1 8.1 14.1 3.7 7.8 8.6 14.9 12.5 22.5 3.9 6.8 8.2 13.4 11.5 20.4 6.8 11.3 13.1 22.9 19.5 34.4 3.4 5.2 5.4 11.1 9 16.2 2.8 4 4.3 8.7 7.2 12.6 -46.4-0.1-92.9 0-139.3 0 -0.8-16.9-3.6-33.9-9.9-49.7 -2.8-8.6-7.4-16.5-11.4-24.6 -4-5.7-6.7-12.3-11.8-17.2 -10.8-15-24.7-27.5-39.5-38.4 -16.8-11.4-35.2-20.8-54.8-26.3 -24.1-7.8-49.8-9.9-75-8.4 -10.1 1.2-20.3 2.4-30.3 4.5 -17 4.7-33.9 10.1-49.2 18.9 -16.4 9.2-32.1 20.1-44.9 34 -15.5 15.1-26.7 34.1-35.3 53.9 -2.8 7.8-5.5 15.6-7 23.7 -3 9.6-3 19.7-4.1 29.7 -50.2-0.2-100.5 0.1-150.8-0.1 1.3-5.2 5.3-9.1 7.5-13.9 8.1-14.2 16.7-28 24.9-42.1 3.4-6.2 7.7-11.9 10.9-18.2 9.1-16.3 19-32.1 28.6-48.1 5.6-10.6 12.4-20.5 17.8-31.2 1.7-3.5 4.7-6.1 6.4-9.6 2.8-6 7-11.3 9.9-17.2 4.6-7.1 8.3-14.8 13.2-21.8 4.2-6.9 7.8-14.1 12.4-20.7 4.9-9 10.4-17.7 15.2-26.7 4.3-6.5 8.2-13.2 12.2-19.8 0.8-1.9 2.5-4 1.8-6 -3.6-1.2-7.5-0.1-11.1-0.9 -1.1-11.9 0.2-23.8-0.5-35.7 0-1.9-0.6-4 0.6-5.6 10.2-0.8 20.4 0.1 30.6-0.3 3.3 0.2 3.7-3.6 4.4-5.9 2.4-9.5 6.3-18.6 8.8-28.1 12-36.6 23.3-73.3 35.1-109.9 2.1-7.7 5.4-15 7.2-22.8 1.4-5.4 3.9-10.5 5-16 0.9-4.5 2.9-8.6 4.1-13 0.2-1 0.6-2.7-0.8-2.9 -7.7-1-15.6 0-23.4 0.3 -2.5-0.9-1.5-3.7-1.5-5.6 0.5-14-0.3-27.9 0.3-41.9 12.2-0.2 24.5 0.1 36.7-0.2 0-5.6 0.6-11.3 1.1-16.9 1-10.1 1.4-20.3 2.6-30.5 1.1-21.6 3.9-43 4.8-64.6 1.5-13.6 2-27.3 3.5-40.9 0.6-18.4 3.1-36.7 4.2-55 0.9-9.3 1-18.7 2.1-28 1.4-15.3 2-30.7 3.8-46.1 0-7.1 0.8-14.1 1.8-21 0.6-13.4 1.6-26.7 3.1-40 1.4-24.3 4.3-48.6 5.5-72.9 0.9-8.6 1.6-17.3 2.1-26 1.6-13.4 1.9-26.9 3.2-40.4 2.3-25.1 3.8-50.2 5.9-75.3 0.9-6.4 0.5-12.9 1.4-19.3 0.8-5.3 1.1-10.6 1.3-16 0.7-7.3 1.4-14.6 1.8-22 0.2-5.7 1.4-11.3 0.9-16.9 -5.2-0.3-10.5-0.1-15.7-0.2 -0.3-12.2-0.3-24.5 0-36.7 5.9-0.2 11.8 0.1 17.7-0.3 0.9-10.8-0.7-21.6 0.8-32.3 4.3-1 8.8-0.2 13.3-0.6 0.4-5.6-0.3-11.2 0.5-16.7 2.2-2 5.8-0.9 8.6-1.4C1466.3 247.3 1465.9 200.7 1466.1 154.2M1430.6 1128.9c-0.7 5-2.6 9.7-3.1 14.7 -0.6 4.9-2.6 9.5-3.4 14.3 -0.9 8.2-3.4 16-5.1 24.1 -2.6 12-5.2 24-7.9 35.9 -1.4 8.9-3.2 17.7-5.7 26.4 -0.5 5.2-2.8 10.2-2.4 15.6 22.7 0.4 45.3 0.1 68 0.2 24.4-0.2 48.7 0.3 73.1-0.2 0.7-6.8-2.3-13.1-3.5-19.7 -3.1-18.7-8-37.1-11.1-55.9 -2.2-9.7-4.8-19.4-6.3-29.3 -1.2-4.3-2.6-8.6-2.9-13.1 -0.2-4.7-2.2-9-2.7-13.6 -0.4-1.9-1-4.9-3.6-4.5 -26.6 0-53.3-0.1-79.9 0.1C1431.1 1123.6 1431 1126.9 1430.6 1128.9z">
  <animate id="EiffelStroke" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="Eiffel.mouseover" from="4617.95" to="0" dur="7.5s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
  <animate id="EiffelFill" attributeName="fill" begin ="EiffelStroke.end" from="#E3FFF0" to="#8DABBA" dur="2.5s" fill="freeze"  /> 
  </path> 
</svg>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/YeRJrx/)

[Live demo](https://svg-art.ru/files/animation/Shopping-Paris/Shopping-Paris3-mp34.html)